# Looping though Rows and Columns while running Goalseek

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, solver

in an Active Worksheet,

I want to create an array of values where in the Macro copies values from a particular cell (let's say **"L5"**) and paste it into target cell (**I4**). Thereafter run goal seek and paste back the values in designated cells. Then goes **L6** and repeats. Do this until there is no value in Column L.

I tried the below code,and it works. But I want to make it short with variables. At the same time run it as a loop until there is no values in column "L"

```
Sub SOLVER()

    Range("L5").Copy
    Range("I4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("J4").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D23")
    Range("D23").Copy
    Range("M5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("H5").Copy
    Range("N5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("L6").Copy
    Range("I4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("J4").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D23")
    Range("D23").Copy
    Range("M6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("H5").Copy
    Range("N6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("L7").Copy
    Range("I4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("J4").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D23")
    Range("D23").Copy
    Range("M7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("H5").Copy
    Range("N7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("L8").Copy
    Range("I4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("J4").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D23")
    Range("D23").Copy
    Range("M8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("H5").Copy
    Range("N8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("L9").Copy
    Range("I4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("J4").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D23")
    Range("D23").Copy
    Range("M9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("H5").Copy
    Range("N9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("L10").Copy
    Range("I4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("J4").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D23")
    Range("D23").Copy
    Range("M10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("H5").Copy
    Range("N10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("L11").Copy
    Range("I4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("J4").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D23")
    Range("D23").Copy
    Range("M11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("H5").Copy
    Range("N11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SOLVER()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    With Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify as needed
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 5 To lastRow
            .Range("I4").Value = .Range("L" & i).Value
            .Range("J4").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Range("D23")
            .Range("M" & i).Value = .Range("D23").Value
            .Range("N" & i).Value = .Range("H5").Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```